# "Step in the right direction"

Tags: phrases, expressions, expression-choice, colloquialisms, concision

What would be a more concise word/phrase to replace "a step in the right direction"?

Tolerance is **a step in the right direction**.

Comment: Could you tell us what is wrong with the original? also, what have you thought of so far?

Comment: I'm trying to find a more *sophisticated* word to use (I've also got a world limit and I'm trying to avoid overused phrases). I can't seem to think of anything that could replace it at all so far.

Comment: "More sophisticated" is a judgement call. Is the tone generally positive or not (it's not easy to tell from a single sentence). "Some small progress" might fit, for example, but that is definitely not generally positive.

Comment: It's not more "sophisticated" (whatever that means), but if you want to reduce word count you could say "Tolerance is **a good start.**"  Both imply that further work is required.

Answer (score 2):

> Tolerance is **a step in the right direction**.

It seems concise enough. However, if you really want to shorten it further:

> Tolerance is **progress**.

Progress implies that it is only a step on a longer journey. So it retains the meaning of it being an incomplete journey (for now, at least).

---

However, the meaning of "right" is lost here. More often than not, "right" is stressed in this context:

> Tolerance is a step in the *right* direction.

Thus implying that it would have also been possible to take a step in the wrong direction.

When you say "progress", you omit any explicit statement about it being right or wrong. When omitted, it can still be inferred to be in the right direction; but rephrasing your sentence has turned an *explicit statement* into an *implication*.

I tend to avoid implications where possible, but you may disagree with me in this particular case.